# Test browsers compatibility with my website

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

Recently users of my website complained about the lack of support to IE6\7.

1. Is there an **offline** tool to test if a page-HTML isn't compatible with a specif browser and **where is the problem**?
2. Where can I find a list of things I need to be aware of in order to support IE6?

**Update:** The problems the users describe are in the UI, `<Div>`are not in the right places and that kind of problems, not JavaScript issues.

I can't force the users to upgrade theirs browsers.

Comment: See: http://iedeathmarch.org/ and http://www.ie6death.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- IE6 is an [ancient browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611/ie6-to-support-or-not-to-support). Tell people who complain about lack of support that it's no longer supported and they should upgrade.
- There is no "syntax checking" tool to find all incompatibilities, because the problems are not in syntax but how it's interpreted. There is no way around visual testing I'm afraid.
- Here are some interesting SO questions on the topic:

  - [One fix for all IE6 problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773464/one-fix-for-all-ie6-problems)
  - [How are programmers tackling ie6 bugs these days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478798/how-are-programmers-tackling-ie6-bugs-these-days)
  - [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-internet-explorer-6-internet-explorer-7-and-internet-explorer-8-on-the)

Comment: I must support IE6. it's intranet and I can't force the users upgared their browser. Though It's the obvious solution...

Comment: @gdoron [even Microsoft is urging users to switch](http://www.ie6countdown.com/)... maybe that can help convince whoever is making the decision

Comment: Even me, That still doesn't help, I can't force those bastard... **=)**

Comment: @gdoron ah well then :) Do check out the linked questions, they contain a lot of good advice.

Answer (score 3):

IE tester is useful for testing across version of internet explorer. It may not tell you what is wrong but you will at least be able to see / verify what users are reporting.

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: +1 IETester is perfect for testing all IE versions without having to setup all kinds of virtual machines with different versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

I have some offer about this for you :

1. Try to use Jquery more,because Jquery is compatible with most browsers
2. there are 3 useful addons for Mozilla : Firebug , Web Developer , IE tab
3. IE 9 has a developer windows that you can change your page standard into IE 8 or 7
4. Use syntax liek this :

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/ie-fix.css" />
   ```

maybe this is useful dude for you  :)

Answer (score 0):

If your users are complaining about IE6, you should give support to IE, thats theory. BUT, if possible do as google has been doing for years, if the user is using IE6/7 or lower show some links to download newer browsers and tell them that their browser is too old.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a seperate stylesheet for IE.
2. There is a third party software named Utilu. Utilu IE Collection contains multiple standalone versions of the browser Internet Explorer, which can be used at the same time. It has more than 10 versions of IE. But its used for viewing the web pages. This software also has firefox and chrome collections.